# Application of Zorns lemma, if a totally ordered subset has a lower bound then it has a minimal element

Tags: general-topology

prove: If every totally ordered subset of an ordered set $X$ has a lower bound in $X$, then $X$ has a minimal element.

proof: Let $X$ be a totally ordered subset. We order $X$ by $f\leq g$ if and only if $f\subset g$. Now, we need to show that $(X,\leq)$ is a partially ordered set. We know, $f,g\in X$, then there must be some $f',g'\in X$, such that $f,g\leq f',g'$ and $f',g'\leq f,g$ then $f,g = f',g'$. We can continue with this reasoning and say that there must be some $f'',g''\in X$ such that $f,g\leq f',g'$ and $f',g'\leq f'',g''$ then $f,g\leq f'',g''$. Now, since $f',g'\leq f'',g''$ then $f',g'\in X$ is a lower bound. Then by Zorns lemma, $f'',g''$ is the minimal element of $X$.

I am wondering if my reasoning is incorrect, if so, could you please share some insight in how I could prove this, having a really hard time with applications of Zorns lemma to prove stuff.

Comment: the way the problem is set up, you should define your partial order on X by the reverse of the given ordering.

Comment: What does $f\subset g$ mean?

Comment: f is a subset of g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X,\le$ be a partially ordered set. Define, for $x,y\in X$,
$$
x\preceq y \text{ if and only if } y\le x
$$
Then

1. $\preceq$ is a partial order on $X$;
2. a subset of $X$ is totally ordered with respect to $\preceq$ if and only it is totally ordered with respect to $\le$
3. a subset of $X$ has an upper bound with respect to $\preceq$ if and only if it has a lower bound with respect to $\le$
4. an element is maximal with respect to $\preceq$ if and only if it is minimal with respect to $\le$

Prove the four propositions above and apply them to your problem.

Comment: Helpful, but easier said then done

Comment: @MorganWeiss It's a very useful tool, that you probably used unconsciously when using $\ge$ along with $\le$ for inequalities in the real numbers: the $\ge$ relation is exactly what here I denoted with $\preceq$

Comment: Is my proof above wrong?

Comment: @MorganWeiss Yes, it's wrong: $f$ and $g$ are element of an abstract partially ordered set, so $f\subset g$ means nothing.